# Why would dome lights stay on, yet moonroof work perfectly? (One unit) 2007 Mercury Montego Premier

Tags: wiring, lights, interior, mercury

**[image: ***strong text***]**

I replaced the unit, but the lights still stay on while the moonroof control operates the moonroof exactly as it should. The one without bulbs is the old one. Removed them to save the battery prior to recieving new unit.

Anyone know what the issue is?